# Converting a VMware player image from non-persistant to persistant

Tags: vmware-player

I'm pondering setting up a virtual machine to generate app-v (since i got mdop from school) or thinapp application virtualisation packages. Ideally with either of these, i should work off a fresh system do the install, then copy out the packages produced.

I'd like to not have to reinstall windows per package to get a fresh, unmodified stock copy of windows. I'm aware that its possible to make a hard disk image persistant in vmware player (one of my lecturers did it, but he's in another country). I'm wondering how would i convert a persistant image to a non persistant one?

I'm currently running vmware player 4, with windows 7 guest and host.